# Devexpress Grid MVC 3 Razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, grid, devexpress

I'm using devexpres grid for mvc3 razor web site... so when I'm trying to change column position (header filter drag and drop option is set to true) icon appears on different place

Image link [here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/5qpnf)

what can I do some advice?

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by the use of some specific CSS rule(s) on the problematic View/Page.

Are you able to replicate this behavior on the [online demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/GridView/FilterRow)?

Comment: no, I'm not able to replicate this behavior on the online demo... :((((